# Opening Page with Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have read around about this a lot and it seems like its an issue that confuses a lot people. I am doing a project with express and I dont want to you any tempting engines, I am using backbone with underscore and thats enough for me. I want to write plain HTML and render them..

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set("view options", {layout: false});
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use( express.cookieParser() );
  app.use(express.session({ secret: 'topsecret' } ));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});
```

this is what I have so far.. I am having a hard time to understand how express knows to render the index.html file as my home page even though I have this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log("Heyyyyyy");
});
```

I would expect nothing to be rendered and "Heyyyy" to be printed but express renders the index.html and doesnt print "Heyyyy"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Express evaluates middleware in the order in which they are configured.

You have a static file handler before your `app.router`.

Take the `index.html` file out of the `__dirname + '/views'` directory.

You also have a static file handler at the bottom of your middleware stack.  Static file handlers should be at the top of your middleware stack.  When they're at the bottom of your middleware stack each request unnecessarily processes all of the stack.  For example, you don't need to run `express.bodyParser()` when serving static files.

Comment: thanks but now the problem is "Error: Cannot find module 'html'" when I try to do res.render('login.html')

Comment: You don't have to render html, just send it ! see [send express doc](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.send)

Comment: You shouldn't be rendering html if you're not using templates.  Just put the login.html in the path you setup for `express.static()` and make sure `express.static()` comes before your `app.router`.

Comment: its just sending text when I do res.send('login.html') ?

Comment: I want to send a file not just a string that contains html

Comment: put the login.html file in `__dirname + '/views'` directory.  Then make a request in your browser for `/login.html`.

Comment: that works thanks, but why did I have to take index.html out of the __dirname + '/views' directory ?

Comment: and how would I ever show login.html inside 

app.get('/', function(req, res){

});